# Spooky query behavior : Same query, different results when inside a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-view

The same query brings different results when inside a View.

I tried to force same codepages, same data types, Common Query Expressions... none worked.

Have a look at this simple query:

```
SELECT TOP 100 CompanyID, SubsidiaryID 
FROM STAGING.SALESAX S
INNER JOIN Subsidiary SU
ON S.CompanyID = SU.SubsidiaryAXCode
```

It returns all expected 100 rows.

If I use the `EXACT SAME QUERY` in a view:

```
CREATE VIEW [STAGING].[VSalesAXBASE]    
AS    
SELECT TOP 100 CompanyID, SubsidiaryID 
FROM STAGING.SALESAX S
INNER JOIN Subsidiary SU
ON S.CompanyID = SU.SubsidiaryAXCode

GO

SELECT * FROM [STAGING].[VSalesAXBASE]
```

it returns 0 ROWS

[image: screenshots of me running the query in two ways]

[image: Screenshot of query updated without TOP Statement]

Comment: Underlying data has changed? Queries were run in the context of different databases? Without a way to replicate this, we can only but guess (which is off topic for Stack Overflow I'm afraid). Also, why a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Hi .. the top is just to show the problem.. the final version won't have it.. but even if I remove it there's no effect. I added a animated gif tho show demonstrate.

Comment: I agree with @Larna SQL resultsets are orderless by SQL standards definition, TOP without using ORDER BY will give you non derministic (random) results in SQL Server to get pure 100% derministic (fixed) results always you should atleast add a column in a ORDER BY clause which has a primary or unique key

Comment: I have a clustered index on the underlying table.. anyway I removed the TOP statement.. the result are still the same..  I will update the topic with a new Screen capture to demonstrate the results

Comment: A clustered index doesn't make a query without an `ORDER BY` have an implicit order. The only way to guarentee a query to return data in a specific order is by using an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: What happens if you try [this](https://pastebin.com/5rHL9cs3). (Note the guessed objects).

Answer (score 2):

You prefix `SALESAX` table with `STAGING.`, but don't prefix `Subsidiary` table in the query. Do prefix all tables in the query.

One possibility is that there are several `Subsidiary` tables and the query uses different table in the context of the view.

By the way, it is also a good practice to prefix columns with table names in the `SELECT` part of the query. For example, right now it is hard to know from which table(s) the columns `CompanyID` and `SubsidiaryID` come from.

Comment: Hi.. no.. there's only one Subsidiary Table.. the STAGING prefix is used for the RAW data after load process. The Subsidiary table is pre-populated before all data loads.

Comment: @Vinny, have you tried to explicitly prefix `Subsidiary` table? It is a good practice to prefix table names with the schema name anyway.

Comment: This looks very likely to be the problem. Note that the View is defined as `[STAGING].[VSalesAXBASE]`; I suspect that will mean it will execute in the context of the `STAGING` schema whereas the manual execution is in the context of the default schema (`dbo`?). So `Subsidiary` without a prefix will mean `dbo.Subsidiary` when run manually, but `STAGING.Subsidiary` when run via the view.

Comment: You are right.. I just added the dbo  schema to the subsidiary table and it Worked... Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the DBO schemma to the subsidiary table.. thanks to the suggestions of @VladimirBaranov, @IMSoP and @Augustina(Codec)

Looks like the execution context of the view may be different from the current user (need to check more on this).

[image: Solution]

Answer (score -1):

SQL does not guarantee the ordering of results unless an explicit Order By clause is used.